# Is it possible to compute with the trapezoidal rule by numerical integration?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, interpolation

Is it possible to compute trapezoidal rule numerical integration?  I know that Mathematica has [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html), and that a list of points can be interpolated and then integrated simply using [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).  However, my functions are highly oscillatory (they are based on simulation data), and I am not convinced that the interpolation is perfect, even when I set [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) to a very high value.  Also, I know that `ListIntegrate` is deprecated, and even if I use it, I am not certain if it is using the trapezoidal rule, which I would like to use.

Do you know if any resources where I can find Mathematica or pseudocode for trapezoidal integration of lists of points?  Or do you have any suggestions about how I can use Mathematica efficiently to program such an algorithm myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not start at the obvious place: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Comment: Actually `NIntegrate[]` indeed is able to perform the trapezoidal rule (see docs for details). I suspect that it won't be the best method for your problem; why not elaborate a bit more on these oscillatory functions you speak of?

Comment: Might check Documentation Center > Integrationtutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies#144042466 and tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules#32844337 for some ideas on option setting for NIntegrate of finite region oscillatory functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
t = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, .01}];
1/2 Total[((#[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]]) (#[[2, 2]] + #[[1, 2]])) & /@  Partition[t, 2, 1]]
(*
-> 1.99998
*)
```

Perhaps better

```
1/2 Total[Differences[t[[All, 1]]] ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, t[[All, 2]]]]
```

They are just

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\approx\frac12\sum_{k=1}^N (x_{k+1}-x_k)(f(x_{k+1})+f(x_k))$$

**Edit**

Just for fun, using JM's shorter expression:

```
Manipulate[
   Column[{
     Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], ListLinePlot[#, Filling -> Axis],
         AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400], 
     Row[{"Approx Integral = ",N@Differences[#1].MovingAverage[#2, 2]& @@ Transpose[#]}]}]&@
     Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/a}],
 {{a, 2, Dynamic[a]}, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Another possibility: `Differences[#1].MovingAverage[#2, 2] & @@ Transpose[t]`.

Comment: In your example using `ListCorrelate` I'd use `Differences[...].ListCorrelate[...]/2` instead of `Total[Differences[...] ListCorrelate[...]]/2` as the intent is clearer.

Comment: @rcollyer I was just showing off my knowledge of commutativity :). Anyway, I think J. M.'s `MovingAverage[]` is better, so I used it in the `Manipulate` example. And yes, `Dot[]` is better than `Total[]` here.

Comment: `MovingAverage` is definitely superior.

Answer (score 3):

The following is quite fast on packed arrays:

```
(Rest@Last@# + Most@Last@#).(Rest@First@# - Most@First@#)/2 &@
 Transpose[t]
```

Small example:

```
t = Developer`ToPackedArray@
   Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Subdivide[0., Pi, 100]}];

Differences[#1].MovingAverage[#2, 2] & @@ Transpose[t] //
 RepeatedTiming
1/2 Total[Differences[t[[All, 1]]] ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, t[[All, 2]]]] //
 RepeatedTiming
(Rest@Last@# + Most@Last@#).(Rest@First@# - Most@First@#)/2 &@ Transpose[t] //
 RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.000036, 1.99984}
  {0.000014, 1.99984}
  {8.5*10^-6, 1.99984}
*)
```

Larger example (autocompiled by `Table`, which produces a packed array):

```
t = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Subdivide[0., Pi, 10000]}];

Differences[#1].MovingAverage[#2, 2] & @@ Transpose[t] //
 RepeatedTiming
1/2 Total[Differences[t[[All, 1]]] ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, t[[All, 2]]]] //
 RepeatedTiming
(Rest@Last@# + Most@Last@#).(Rest@First@# - Most@First@#)/2 &@ Transpose[t] //
 RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.0004, 2.}
  {0.00050, 2.}
  {0.000093, 2.}
*)
```

Comment: Super.
 Your Method "Rest@Last@ ..." is very fast.
Would you kindly show use how to use this for an vector of functions like{Sin[x],Cos[x],Tan[x]} .

Comment: @GummalaNavneeth Perhaps ``xx = Subdivide[0., Pi/4., 100];
vv = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x]} /. x -> xx // Developer`ToPackedArray;
(vv[[All, 2 ;;]] + vv[[All, ;; -2]]) . (Rest@xx - Most@xx)/2``, if you get to generate the data. Advantage of converting to a packed array diminishes as the length of `xx` approaches `10^6`, at which point it becomes a disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

The Wolfram Demonstrations Project has this [demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NumericalIntegrationUsingRectanglesTheTrapezoidalRuleOrSimps/).   It might provide an idea or two to help.