# Area or NIntegrate curves defined by points?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

Is there a convenient method to compute the AUC (Area Under the Curve) metric that quantifies a [Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) like shown here?

[image]

The data used to build the ROC are just pairs of real values in `[0,1]`:

```
{{1, 1}, {15/64, 30/73}, {5/64, 21/218}, {3/64, 5/109}, {1/64, 3/
  109}, {0, 2/109}, {0, 1/109}}
```

Although this data can be closed to form a polytope, documentation for [Area](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Polytopes/ref/Area.html) states that polytope edges need to be unit-length, which is not the case in general.

Is there a convenient way to pass this data to `NIntegrate`, and if so what integration methods (eg, Trapezoid vs ..) and interpolation are appropriate for the ROC AUC problem?

Comment: You have 2 points with the same x-axis value, 0. Is this desired?

Comment: @s0rce, the map from a threshold parameter to (sensitivity, 1-specificity) need not be injective. Potentially this is an interesting issue as to whether it would affect integration (or duplicate points should be removed - but that introduces a different problem since often the optimal threshold is what is sought)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps just

```
data = {{1, 1}, {15/64, 30/73}, {5/64, 21/218}, {3/64, 5/109}, {1/64, 3/109}, {0, 2/109}, 
N@Total[Partition[Sort@data,2,1] /.{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}} -> (x2 - x1) (y1 + (y2 - y1)/2)]

(*
-> 0.583492
*)
```

made by adding up rectangles and triangles:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: [Reminds me...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5629) `#[[2, 1]] + (#[[2, 2]] - #[[2, 1]])/ 2` ought to be `#[[1, 2]] + (#[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]])/ 2`.

Comment: @J.M. shifted to a more readable form

Comment: Why not use the form in your other answer? :)

Comment: @J.M. I'm too lazy to visit a link to learn how I calculated this sum before. There are surely a zillion ways to sum these products

Answer (score 4):

Since your last data point had the same x-axis value I just dropped it for this answer, I wasn't sure if it was real.

```
data = {{1, 1}, {15/64, 30/73}, {5/64, 21/218}, {3/64, 5/109}, {1/64, 
    3/109}, {0, 2/109}, {0, 1/109}};
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

```
dataint = Interpolation[Most@data, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
NIntegrate[dataint[x], {x, 0, 1}]

(*

7387756019/10816427520

*)

Plot[NIntegrate[dataint[x], {x, 0, y}], {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

Alternatively,

```
Total[data[[All,2]]]

(*

25593/15914

*)
```

Comment: By looking at the plot provided in the question, I think repeated x values are allowed