# Trapezoid Integration over a list of pairs

Tags: numerical-integration

I have two very connected questions:

Is there really no built-in function to integrate a list of pairs without converting to a function? Something like:

```
NIntegrate[{{x1, y1}, ..., {xn, yn}}]
```

I am aware of `Interpolation`, but do not want to use it.

If there is no  built-in function, is there a possibility to improve my following function (I stole the important part from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/is-it-possible-to-compute-trapezoidal-rule-numerical-integration))?

```
 rangeSelect[table_, range_] := 
   Select[table, range[[1]] <= #[[1]] <= range[[2]] &]
 trapezoidIntegration[list_, range_] := 
   Differences[#1].MovingAverage[#2, 2] & @@ Transpose[rangeSelect[list, range]]
```

=======1. Edit

I think I have to clarify what I intended with defining rangeSelect[matrix,{a,b}]
This function should slice out all those rows from the 2D array "matrix" in the form of {{x1,y1},...,{xn,yn}} where the x value is larger than a and smaller than b.

=======2. Edit

My function introduces errors at the beginning and end of the integration interval. Since my data is automatically sampled hence has a lot of points this is not so important for me. This is also the reason, why I did not think about non integrable 1 element lists. For the same data as in m_goldberg's answer but with n=10^4 `trapezoidIntegration`and `Integrate[Interpolation[...]]` give the same result.

Comment: why do you not want to use interpolate?

Comment: I have experimental data and used interpolate with an Order 6. Already from the plots you see that it does not represent my data very well.

Comment: In addition the normal trapezoidIntegration[] of the list gives quite a good value of the integral while NIntegrate[Inperpolation[...]] is orders of magnitude away from the literature values.

Comment: Can you show a plot of your data?

Comment: By the way: look up `InterpolationOrder`.

Comment: It seems like you're asking, is there a better answer to the linked question than presently exists?  Or perhaps your question is about `rangeSelect`?

Comment: When looking up InterpolationOrder and after repeating the answers given I realized that this is a case where "the more the better" does not apply. Without much thinking I thought a higher degree of polynomials would improve the situation which seems not to be the case.

Comment: @J.M.isback. Now the difference between the plotted data and the interpolation function vanishes as well.

Comment: "Higher order does not always imply higher accuracy." - often repeated advice.

Comment: @J.M.isback. I used now several times Interpolation-Integration but it gives worse results. I would like to edit my question and append the actual data, but I don't know how I should include huge lists.

Comment: You can try putting it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and linking to it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am going to argue against your rejection of using `Interpoation`.

**Generated data**

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 12}, data = Transpose[{Range[n] // N, RandomReal[12., n]}]];
```

Applying the trapezoidal rule directly gives

```
Total[.5 (#[[1, 2]] + #[[2, 2]]) & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]]
```

> ```
> 55.0291
> ```

(Perhaps you can adapt this to your work if you don't buy my argument.)

**First-order interpolation**

```
dataF = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Does `dataF` accurately represents the data?

```
Table[{i, dataF[i]}, {i, 1., 12.}] == data
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Therefore,

```
NIntegrate[dataF[x], {x, 1., 12.}, 
  Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule", "RombergQuadrature" -> False}]
```

> ```
> 55.0291
> ```

And this reflects IMO good *Mathematica* practice for handling this kind of quadrature problem. However, with this particular generated data set, there is no reason to explicitly force the trapezoid rule because the naive evaluation

```
NIntegrate[dataF[x], {x, 1., 12.}]
```

> ```
> 55.0291
> ```

works just as well.

Comment: This also works efficiently: `Integrate[dataF[x], x] /. x -> 12`.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Indeed, but the OP explicitly asked about applying the trapezoid rule, and I felt constrained to stick with that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Integrate` uses the trapezoid rule, if `InterpolationOrder` is `1`.  And it's quite a bit faster than the `NIntegrate` alternative you propose.

Answer (score 8):

First, the answer to the OP's question about a built-in function is given here:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/ref/ListIntegrate.html

It says since version 6, one should use `Integrate` with `Interpolation` like this:

```
Integrate[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder ->k], {x, a, b}]
```

where `k = 1` in this case.  In other words the old built-in `ListIntegrate`, which used to do what the OP desires, has been decommissioned.

---

Using [m_goldberg's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) data, `ListCorrelate`, slightly modified from [belisarius's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius-is-forth) answer to [Is it possible to compute with the trapezoidal rule by numerical integration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/is-it-possible-to-compute-trapezoidal-rule-numerical-integration), is the fastest alternative I've found:

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 12}, data = Transpose[{Range[n] // N, RandomReal[12., n]}]];

1/2 Differences[data[[All, 1]]]. ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, data[[All, 2]]]
```

---

I'm not sure what the `rangeSelect` is intended to do.  For instance,

```
rangeSelect[data, {2.5, 3.5}]
```

results in an un-integrable list:

```
{{3., 4.16483}}
```

Similar trimming of the interval is likely for any call to `rangeSelect`, although one may get a list of length greater than one:

```
rangeSelect[data, {2.5, 4.5}]
(*  {{3., 4.16483}, {4., 5.44489}}  *)
```

If the integral over the interval `{2.5, 3.5}` of the trapezoidal approximation is intended, then we can apply `Integrate` as recommended in the documentation:

```
dataF = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Integrate[dataF[x], {x, 2.5, 3.5}]
```

(again using m_goldberg's `data` and interpolation `dataF`).