# NIntegrate not working after interpolation

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, fourier-analysis

I used linear interpolation between points:

```
T = 1;
w = 0.05;
num = 1000;
A = 1;

pulse[x_] := A*(UnitStep[x + w*T/2] - UnitStep[x - w*T/2])

fun = 
  Table[pulse[x] + 0.2*(RandomReal[] - 0.5), {x, -T/2, T/2, 
    T/(num - 1)}];
funX = Table[i, {i, -T/2, T/2, T/(num - 1)}];

funINT = 
  Interpolation[Transpose[{funX[[All]], fun[[All]]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

 ListPlot[Transpose[{funX[[All]], fun[[All]]}], PlotRange -> All, 
  Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time [s]", "Amplitude [V]"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Pulse"}, 
  ImageSize -> 
   Large]
```

This produces exactly what I want:
[image: plot]

But in order to calculate the coefficients of complex Fourier series, I have to calculate the following integral:

```
    cn[k_] = NIntegrate[funINT[t]*Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T, {t, -T/2, T/2}, 
                        Method -> "Trapezoidal"];
```

which is not working. I get an error saying that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values. Any ideas on what the problem is?

EDIT: If there is a method to calculate the integral between the discrete points, that might be even better in my case. However, I couldn't find one.

Comment: Try `cn[k_] := `, i.e. use `SetDelayed`. As it stands, you are telling _Mathematica_ to evaluate the RHS immediately, but `NIntegrate` cannot do that for non-numerical `k`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: I am familiar with that solution, yes. However it has a huge problem: Once I try to evaluate the Fourier series for 1000 terms I takes for ages to evaluate `rekon[t, 1000]` if `rekon[t_, st_] := Sum[cn[n]*Exp[I*2*Pi*n*t/T], {n, -st, st}]`. That is why I would like to somehow do the integration with `k` as parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find a general symbolic Fourier coefficient for a linear polynomial and use the formula to integrate the interpolating function piecewise. If you're content with machine precision (double precision), then you can `Compile` it for really great speed.

```
(* Basic integral formulas *)
ClearAll[cn0];
cn0[0][{t0_, t1_}, {x0_, x1_}] = (* k == 0 is a special case *)
    Integrate[(x0 + (x1 - x0)/(t1 - t0) (t - t0)) * Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T /. k -> 0,
   {t, t0, t1}];
cn0[k_][{t0_, t1_}, {x0_, x1_}] =
  Integrate[(x0 + (x1 - x0)/(t1 - t0) (t - t0)) * Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T,
   {t, t0, t1}];

(* Coefficient function *)
Clear[cn];
cn[0] = Total@
   MapThread[ (* map over interpolation segments *)
    cn0[0],
    {Partition[funX, 2, 1], Partition[fun, 2, 1]}];
cn[k_] = Total@
   MapThread[
    cn0[k],
    {Partition[funX, 2, 1], Partition[fun, 2, 1]}];

(* Compiled version *)
cnC = With[ (* basic integrals *)
   {i0 = Function[{t0, t1, x0, x1}, (* k == 0 is a special case *)
      Evaluate@ Integrate[
        (x0 + (x1 - x0)/(t1 - t0) (t - t0)) * Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T /. k -> 0,
        {t, t0, t1}]],
    i = Function[{t0, t1, x0, x1}, 
      Evaluate@ Integrate[
        (x0 + (x1 - x0)/(t1 - t0) (t - t0)) * Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T,
        {t, t0, t1}]]},
   Compile[{{k, _Integer}, {t, _Real, 1}, {x, _Real, 1}},
    Total@If[k == 0,
      i0[Most[t], Rest[t], Most[x], Rest[x]], (* vectorized for speed *)   
      i[Most[t], Rest[t], Most[x], Rest[x]]]
    ]];
```

Checks and comparison of speeds:

```
(* OP's method for comparison *)
cn1[k_] := 
  NIntegrate[funINT[t]*Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T, {t, -T/2, T/2}, 
   Method -> "Trapezoidal"];

res1 = Table[cn1[k], {k, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
res2 = Table[cn[k], {k, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
res3 = Table[cnC[k, funX, fun], {k, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{6.41549, {0.0509924, 0.0485667 + 0.000384561 I, 
  0.0489479 + 0.000373475 I, 0.0489737 + 0.000976852 I, 
  0.0459565 + 0.00132399 I, 0.0452069 + 0.000833868 I}}

{0.154046, {0.0509924, 0.0485667 + 0.000384561 I, 
  0.0489479 + 0.000373475 I, 0.0489737 + 0.000976852 I, 
  0.0459565 + 0.00132399 I, 0.0452069 + 0.000833868 I}}

{0.001207, {0.0509924 + 0. I, 0.0485667 + 0.000384561 I, 
  0.0489479 + 0.000373475 I, 0.0489737 + 0.000976852 I, 
  0.0459565 + 0.00132399 I, 0.0452069 + 0.000833868 I}}
*)

res1 - res2
res2 - res3
(*
{6.26145, {-6.245*10^-17, -1.27026*10^-10 - 3.56074*10^-10 I, 
  5.71595*10^-12 - 8.24057*10^-11 I, -5.08276*10^-10 - 1.50366*10^-11 I, 
  8.25427*10^-11 - 4.73669*10^-10 I, -3.07932*10^-10 + 1.72791*10^-10 I}}

{0.152839, {-1.38778*10^-17 + 0. I, -3.7817*10^-15 - 1.49451*10^-14 I,
   1.1019*10^-14 - 3.11627*10^-15 I, -1.10328*10^-15 - 2.62073*10^-15 I,
   -3.42781*10^-15 - 8.26162*10^-17 I, 1.88738*10^-15 - 1.13711*10^-15 I}}
*)
```

So `cn` is almost 50 times faster than `NIntegrate` and `cnC` is over 100 times faster than `cn`.

Comment: I was wandering should I answer this question or first wait and see would you answer it... :)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Ha-ha. :)

Comment: @skrat The `(x0 + (x1 - x0)/(t1 - t0) (t - t0))` is the point-slope formula for the interpolating line between `{t0, x0}` and `{t1, x1}` as a function of `t`, which is the formula used by the order-1 interpolation. So `i` (and `i0` for `k == 0`) is the value of the integral over a general piece of the interpolation in terms of `k` and two interpolation points (`t0`, `t1`, `x0`, `x1`).

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to approach answering this question.

### Not using NIntegrate

One approach is to use direct Trpezoidal formula integration as shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5629/34008) of ["Is it possible to compute with the trapezoidal rule by numerical integration?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5627/34008).

### Using NIntegrate's range specification

> If there is a method to calculate the integral between the discrete points, that might be even better in my case. However, I couldn't find one.

`NIntegrate`'s range specification can take range splitting points. In this case we put the points `funX` in the range specification with `Evaluate[{t, Sequence @@ funX}]`.

```
Clear[cn]
cn[k_] := 
  NIntegrate[funINT[t]*Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T, 
   Evaluate[{t, Sequence @@ funX}], PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

Clear[rekon]
rekon[t_, st_] := Sum[cn[n]*Exp[I*2*Pi*n*t/T], {n, -st, st}]

In[74]:= AbsoluteTiming[res = rekon[t, 100];]    
Out[74]= {33.411, Null}

In[75]:= AbsoluteTiming[res = rekon[t, 1000];]
Out[75]= {360.723, Null}
```

### Using a specially made rule for a list of functions

We can apply the approach given in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126041/34008) of the question ["How to calculate the numerical integral more efficiently?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126001/34008).

We make a list of all the integrands formed in `rekon` and we integrate them at once with [`ArrayOfFunctionsRule`](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Misc/ArrayOfFunctionsRule.m). The computations are 8-10 times faster.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/ArrayOfFunctionsRule.m"]

Clear[n, st, t]
With[{st = 1000},
 factors = Table[Exp[I*2*Pi*n*t/T], {n, -st, st}];
 funcs = Table[funINT[t]*Exp[-I*2*Pi*k*t/T]/T, {k, -st, st}];
 ]

AbsoluteTiming[
 res = NIntegrate[1, Evaluate[{t, Sequence @@ funX}],
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
    Method -> {"UnitCubeRescaling", "FunctionalRangesOnly" -> True, 
      Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None, 
        Method -> {ArrayOfFunctionsRule, "Functions" -> funcs}}}];
]

(* {39.5742, Null} *)

res.factors
```

Answer (score 3):

Michael's and Anton's answers involve the manual splitting of the piecewise linear functions involved in the computation of the Fourier coefficients at the interpolation points. Yet another way to tell *Mathematica* to automatically split the integrand before integrating is to use the option setting `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`, like so:

```
With[{T = 1, w = 0.05, num = 1000, A = 1},
     BlockRandom[SeedRandom["many pulses"]; (* for reproducibility *)
     funINT = Interpolation[Table[{x, A (UnitStep[x + w T/2] - UnitStep[x - w T/2]) +
                                      RandomReal[{-1, 1} 0.1]},
                                  {x, -T/2, T/2, T/(num - 1)}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]]];

With[{T = 1}, 
     Table[NIntegrate[funINT[t] Exp[-2 π I k t/T]/T, {t, -T/2, T/2}, 
                      Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"], {k, 0, 5}]]
   {0.0511259271805279, 0.05148235941558258 - 0.001596805628001697*I,
    0.05010102394935553 - 0.0007387015194085259*I,
    0.05130250748609571 + 0.0018324339082365982*I,
    0.04620591693520239 - 0.00029540402973357425*I,
    0.04467904044269826 + 0.0016773681935466633*I}
```

Comment: Yeah of course I should have mentioned `"InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` in my answer!