# Integration of a rapidly oscillating function

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I have a function `F` which behaves like you can see on the plot shown below. I need to calculate

```
NIntegrate[F[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

but it returns a huge result, something like 10^80. If I apply `Method -> "LevinRule"`, it still returns an unreasonable number. How can I caluclate the integral?

Perhaps it will help if I tell you that the function is based on Laguerre polynomials.

[image: plot]

Here is the code defining the function via some number of auxiliary functions and variables

```
Z = 88
n = 120
k = -2
m = 1
alpha = 7.2973525664*^-3
alpha = alpha*Z
nr = n - Abs[k]
gam = Sqrt[k^2 - (alpha)^2]
enk = m/Sqrt[1 + (alpha)^2/(nr + gam)^2]
cnk = Sqrt[m^2 - enk^2]
ap = If[nr == 0, 0,
  ap = Sqrt[(cnk (nr - 1)!  / 
    Gamma[nr + 2 gam + 1])*
     ( (nr + gam + gam/k*Sqrt[alpha^2 + (nr + gam)^2])/
        (2 gam^2/k^2 (alpha^2 + (nr + gam)^2)))]]
am = Sqrt[(cnk*nr!  / 
  Gamma[nr + 2 gam])*
   ( (nr + gam - gam/k*Sqrt[alpha^2 + (nr + gam)^2])/
      (2 gam^2/k^2 (alpha^2 + (nr + gam)^2)))]
up[r_] := (2 cnk*r)^gam*Exp[-cnk*r]*ap*2 cnk*r*
  LaguerreL[nr - 1, 2 gam + 1, 2 cnk*r]
um[r_] := (2 cnk*r)^gam*Exp[-cnk*r]*am*
  LaguerreL[nr, 2 gam - 1, 2 cnk*r]
g[r_] := 1/Sqrt[2 k (k - gam)]*(alpha*up[r] - (k - gam) um[r])
f[r_] := 1/Sqrt[2 k (k - gam)]*(alpha*um[r] - (k - gam) up[r])
rho[r_] := Abs[g[r]]^2 + Abs[f[r]]^2
NIntegrate[rho[r], {r, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "LevinRule"]
Plot[rho[r], {r, 0, 55000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It is impossible!, because we do not know the `F[r]` function.Give it to see what we can do.

Comment: does the function end like that at 50,000 or keep oscillating? If it keeps growing it obviously diverges.

Comment: If the integration range is finite you can find the zeroes of function (or extrema points) and integrate between them. See the answers in [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132698/34008) for integration between a given set of points.

Comment: Have you tried a higher `WorkingPrecision`?

Comment: Dear friends, thank you for your replies. As asked, I have attached the code defining the function. I tried also different WorkingPrecision and integration by small pieces (though not between zeros). No progress.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit of experimentation indicates that  `"LevinRule"` does not work well, and that `"MaxErrorIncreases"` and `MaxRecursion` must be increased.  Most importantly, `WorkingPrecision` must be increased substantially.  To do so, first increase the precision of the only finite precision constant.

```
alpha = SetPrecision[7.2973525664*^-3, 65];
```

Then, set the options of `NIntegrate` as follows.

```
NIntegrate[rho[r], {r, 0, 55000}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
    "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 2000}, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 60, PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
(* 0.999999999862974654189196482270003235458935716234694791163667 *)
```

as desired.  `AbsoluteTiming` for the computation is 1.4 seconds.

Comment: I think the `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"` is a red herring. I get your result merely with the increased precision and recursion (and the restriction to the effective support of the integrand).

Comment: @MichaelE2  Actually, my claim is that "ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule" works better than "LevinRule",  I chose the former over other rules I tried, because it was slightly faster, at least for `n == 30`, for which I ran a number of tests.  By the way, nice answer (+1).

Comment: I see (& thanks, and +1 to you, too). The choice of the Levin rule, btw, is inappropriate because there is no oscillatory component of the integrand (high-degree polynomials don't count for it). In fact, `Method -> "LevinRule"` with your other changes gives an accurate result (albeit by rejecting Levin and using Gauss-Kronrod). I don't know much about `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"` beyond the docs, which indicate that the integrand is not of the appropriate form for it either; but mainly I was just suggesting your answer could be simplified.

Comment: Interesting side note: Looking at what `"ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"` actually does in this case, I see it is effectively equivalent to `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 20}`. Not sure if that's normal or not.

Answer (score 11):

#### The source of the problem

The problem is the expansion of `LaguerreL[]`, with degree `nr == 118`.  If it is evaluated with a symbolic argument `r`, it will expand to power series form (the usual linear combination of powers of `r`); in this form, it is impossible to evaluate accurately at machine precision.  A very high precision is needed, and in addition, the machine precision coefficients, which derive from the definition of `alpha`, need to have their precision increased.  I set `` alpha = 7.2973525664`100*^-3 `` for the following.  For example, compare the plots:

```
Plot[rho[r], {r, 0, 55000}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Evaluated on a numeric argument"]

Plot[Evaluate@rho[r], {r, 0, 55000}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Evaluated on a symbolic argument, with low precision"]

Plot[Evaluate@Rationalize[rho[r], 0], {r, 0, 55000}, PlotRange -> All,
  WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
 PlotLabel -> "Evaluated on a symbolic argument, with insufficient precision"]

Plot[Evaluate@Rationalize[rho[r], 0], {r, 0, 55000}, PlotRange -> All, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 60, 
 PlotLabel -> "Evaluated on a symbolic argument, with high precision"]
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Here we can see why `WorkingPrecision -> 60` was successful in [@bbgodfrey's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey) answer.

#### An easy fix to the problem

The trick is to evaluate `LaguerreL[]` only on numeric arguments using [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) to control the evaluation.  The built-in routine will evaluate `LaguerreL[]` accurately on machine precision inputs.  This may be used closest to the source of the problem in `up[]` and `um[]` or simply on the top-level function `rho[]`:

```
(* with alpha = 7.2973525664`*^-3, machine precision as in the OP *)
ClearAll[rho];
rho[r_?NumericQ] := Abs[g[r]]^2 + Abs[f[r]]^2; 
NIntegrate[rho[r], {r, 0, Infinity}, MinRecursion -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 20] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.727109, 1.0000000000001033`}   *)
```

I wouldn't consider this an oscillatory integral, since it eventually stops oscillating. (The Levin rule expects an oscillatory function like `Sin[]` or `BesselJ[]` etc.)  However it does have many oscillation, so a sufficiently fine sampling is necessary, which is the purpose of `MinRecursion -> 3` above.  This could also be achieved with a high number of sample points, such as `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 61}`.

Splitting the interval up can speed things up in this case, since the function effectively has support over a finite interval and is analytic. Something like this takes only 0.32 sec.:

```
NIntegrate[rho[r], {r, 0, 50000, Infinity}, Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}]
```

One final remark: The integral can be evaluated symbolically; but it takes a really long time, and the numerics issue of the expanded polynomial persists.  Below is a relatively fast way, since the integrand, after removing the unnecessary `Abs`, expands into a linear combination of terms of the form `Exp[-cnt r] * r^s` for various powers `s`.

```
alpha = 7.2973525664`200*^-3;
(* ... re-execute OP's defs ...*)

i[s_] = Integrate[E^(-2 cnk r) r^s, {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> s > 0];

List @@ (rho[r] /. Abs -> Identity // Expand) /. E^(-2 cnk r)*r^s_ :> i[s] // Total
(*1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*)
```